# Excel VBA to search each field of a column and delete the row if it does not include 'apprentice' or 'Apprentice'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write code that will loop through a column (column O) and delete rows that do not contain the words 'apprentice' or 'Apprentice' anywhere. Unfortunately the code deletes everything, though bizzarely it kept one row with 'labourer'.

The first row are headers.

I have tried the following code:

```
    Dim RowNum as Long

    For RowNum = Range("O65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step - 1

    With Cells(RowNum, "O")
        If InStr(1, LCase(.Value), "apprentice") = 0 Then
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With

    Next RowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

use the VBA `Like` operator for string matching.

```vb
Dim RowNum as Long

For RowNum = Range("O65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step - 1
    If Not LCase(Range("O" & RowNum).Text) Like "*apprentice*" Then Rows(RowNum).Delete
Next RowNum
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get a Run-Time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' falied. Any ideas?

Comment: That's strange, it worked on my tests. Debug.print to check rownum is positive, or try qualifying the range references by adding a sheet reference before them (there are multiple `Range(` references in the code, identifying which one is causing the problem would be a big step forward)

Comment: It was my fault, your code works great. The only problem is the column has a filter, and this code is ignoring the filter. Is there anyway I can change the code  to only work on visible cells?

Comment: You'll need to add it as an extra condition in the `If` statement - something like `If Rows(rownum).hidden = false And Not LCase( ... Then ... `